# Flutter and Firestore: How can access variables from Stateful Widget to create a new document?

Tags: dart, google-cloud-firestore, flutter

i want to use a final variable from a StatefulWidget inside a StatelessWidget to create a new document in Firestore.

But i get always the same issue: Only static members can be accessed in initializers

My StatefulWidget Code:

```
class UserProfile extends StatefulWidget {
  UserProfile({this.auth, this.onSignedOut, this.userID});
  final BaseAuth auth;
  final VoidCallback onSignedOut; 
  final String userID;

   @override
     _UserProfileState createState() => new _UserProfileState();

}
```

My StatelessWidget Code:

```
class _UserProfilState extends State<UserProfile> {
  final DocumentReference userdocuments = 
    Firestore.instance.collection("Users").document(widget.userID); //Here i get the Error, because widget.userID
}
```

My Question: How can i use the the userID Variable from the StatefulWidget, to create a new document based on the userID. Thanks for our help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the value in the `initState` method

```
class _UserProfilState extends State<UserProfile> {

DocumentReference userdocuments;

@override
 void initState() {
   userdocuments = 
   Firestore.instance.collection("Users").document(widget.userID);
   super.initState();
  }
}
```